# How to create a .jar file or export JAR in IntelliJ IDEA (like Eclipse Java archive export)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was using IntelliJ IDEA IDE. I want to create a JAR file from Java compiled class files. But I didn't find a command or file.

How to create a JAR file (like it is done in Eclipse)?

Comment: I couldn't do it via Intellij, so I found [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-desktop) and it is super easy to generate the package via ./gradlew desktop:dist, I know it is not related with the question, but it really helped me in the task of creating the jar file.

Comment: please mark the answer that helped you the most. It help readers identify the right/useful answer :)

Answer (score 443):

*For Intellij IDEA version 11.0.2*

**File | Project Structure | Artifacts**
then you should press **alt+insert** or click the plus icon and create new artifact choose --> **jar --> From modules with dependencies.**

Next goto **Build | Build artifacts** --> choose your artifact.

source:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Comment: For anyone coming here that can't get it work. It worked for me when I stored the .mf file in the root directory and **not** in the /src/ folder.

Comment: It says cant load the main class.. :(

Comment: I always get "error: Class names, 'myStuff.jar', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested 1 error" when I run the jar

Comment: I can't tell if it works or not, where the file itself ? I need t copy the jar file but cannot find it (I am working on Ubutnu)

Comment: @McLan I have Ubuntu too and if you do everything like he said, you will find a new folder in your project root named 'out'. Just open all the folders inside of it and at the end you will find your .jar file.

Comment: I managed to create the jar file but for some reason when I am trying to extract the jar file I am getting currupted error.

Answer (score 52):

You didn't specify your IDEA version. Before 9.0 use **Build | Build Jars**, in IDEA 9.0 use **Project Structure | Artifacts**.

Comment: Well here's how to do it with Intellij 10 is http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Comment: I am trying to build jar but i got error failed to load main-class manifest attribute from jar file. I have included external library also. Why the error comes

Comment: I get this also, Muthu.  The MANIFEST.MF created by intellij/maven does not have a populated class path in my case.  I simply use "mvm -e package" from the command line instead.

Comment: @ctpenrose `mvm -e package` where setup ?  command tool or intellij IDE ?

Comment: @zhaoyou he meant `mvn -e package`, and you're supposed to run it on command line within the root directory of the project. this will generate a `jar` inside the `target` folder. however, this is probably exactly what IntelliJ does itself.

Answer (score 4):

In intellij8 I was using a specific plugin "Jar Tool" that is configurable and allows to pack a JAR archive.