# Jar'ing Java project, and not one class

Tags: java, jar

I want to create a jar file of a Java project, which compiles. I've looked on the internet but all the examples of how to do this seem to take one java file and work on that. I want to jar the root of the java project. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I am using IntelliJ if you mean IDE.

Comment: I would be **extremely** surprised if IntelliJ didn't have facilities for doing just this and easily too.

Comment: I also think intelliJ has this builtin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### IntelliJ

According to this [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-ex) you can built jar file using

> You didn't specify your IDEA version.
>   Before 9.0 use Build | Build Jars, in
>   IDEA 9.0 use Project Structure |
>   Artifacts.

### Maven

You should learn to use a build tool like maven. You then could use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>attached</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <configuration>
           <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
           </descriptorRefs>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <mainClass>*******your main class******</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Ant

Or you could use [ant](http://ideoplex.com/id/1339/building-an-executable-jar-with-ant)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant) to create a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html) to the tutorial that might help.

Answer (score 0):

The jar command takes either files or directories. So you can simply specify the name of the directory that you want to jar rather than a file name. Once you know the command to jar a single file then you can jar a directory. More details [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html).

And [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) shows an example of jaring a file and a number of directories together.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know why it doesn't work, that is because there are no java-related env variables on my Windows system. What env variables do I need?

Comment: You need to add the location where java's jdk is installed to the path variable at least. I don't think anything else is required.