# Compile package to library .jar

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm my project I've created a sub package `.helpers` and wrote some classes for doing various things I do a lot to make things quicker in the long run, now I want to compile my `.helpers` package into a jar file so I can include it as a library in any future projects I do. Is this something I can do within Android Studio?

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e) but in Android Studio I don't get the **File | Project Structure | Artifacts**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a plain Java module for your code, the build process will automatically create a jar of it and put it in the **build/libs** directory. If you want more explicit control over jar file generation, you can read about the Java plugin's jar task at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html