# Running a java project in terminal with multiple .java files (multiple attempts described inside)

Tags: java, bash, intellij-idea, compilation, classpath

I have been doing a coding exercise inside the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14 IDE, using OpenJDK.

The project is split over 4 .java files all in the same package.
My end goal is to run this in the terminal/bash (I use System.console().readLine() which doesnt play nicely in the IDE's console).

I've tried navigating to the directory where these 4 files reside (they all reside in the same dir) and tried:

```
javac -classpath . BibliotecaApp.java Book.java BookManager.java LibraryDB.java
```

This creates 4 corresponding .class files fine.
The Main is in bibliotecaApp.java/class, so I try run it by:

```
java BibliotecaApp
```

But I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BibliotecaApp (wrong name: com/twu/biblioteca/BibliotecaApp)
```

Plus about 13 lines of specifics.

Now googling this error seems to be a class path problem, and this is where I get stuck.
From places I've read, using`echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

This is still from the directory of the .java files above.
That path means nothing to me. I have no idea what it is or what it does, or what even a classpath is! Theres alot of resources out there on setting a classpath, but they aren’t helping me because I don't know what it's meant for.

That was a dead end for me. I tried to create a .jar instead using IDEA's `Build Artifacts` as seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e). It created a .jar file but when I navigate to that directory and try run it via:

```
java -jar  biblioteca_jar
```

I get

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile biblioteca_jar
```

Another issue is that in the file explorer, the file actually comes out as biblioteca.jar, but ls on that dir shows biblioteca_jar. Is that normal?

The code is on my GitHub if that helps anything
https://github.com/botagar/twu-biblioteca-JohnGeddes

Comment: Is your `bibliotecaApp.java/class` file really starts with lowercase b? I think that might be a problem.

Comment: Sorry no, it's Capital B. I just wrote it wrongly in the post. Rest of it is still as is.
The .jar file though IS lower case 'b'.

Comment: Also I think you need the full name: `java com.twu.biblioteca.BibliotecaApp` running in the `out/production` folder

Comment: `java out/production/biblioteca/com.twu.biblioteca.BibliotecaApp` Gives me the same error :(

Comment: Sorry, it should be run in `out/production/biblioteca`. That seem to work for me checking out your code

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. Got it cleared up! Still have problems with the .jar, but it's not critical. Does worry me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your compiler step, change this

```
java BibliotecaApp
```

to

```
java -cp . BibliotecaApp
```

Which will add the current directory to the classpath for the java runtime environment. See also the Oracle Technote [Setting the Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

A jar file is a kind of zip, and should have a `.jar` extension. So this

```
java -jar  biblioteca_jar
```

should probably be

```
java -jar  biblioteca.jar
```

And you can check if the file is valid with any zip archive reader. Including jar itself,

```
jar tvvf biblioteca.jar
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments below,

```
cd ~/Documents/ThoughtWorks Uni/TWU_Biblioteca-master/src/
```

and then

```
java -cp . com.twu.biblioteca.BibliotecaApp
```

Comment: I get the same 
`jgeddes@ubuntu:~/Documents/ThoughtWorks Uni/TWU_Biblioteca-master/src/com/twu/biblioteca$ java -cp . BibliotecaApp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BibliotecaApp (wrong name: com/twu/biblioteca/BibliotecaApp)`

Comment: Edited. Next time for better help sooner please specify that kind of detail in your original question.

Comment: Thanks, It worked (for running the .class). I wasn't aware that it had to be run from the root? package.
However, trying to check the .jar if its valid, there are issues.
Both `jar tvvf biblioteca.jar` and `jar tvvf biblioteca_jar` return `java.io.FileNotFoundException: biblioteca.jar (No such file or directory)` and `java.io.FileNotFoundException: biblioteca_jar (Is a directory)`. The biblioteca_jar was generated by IDEA. I have no idea why in the file explorer it has a .jar extension but in bash, it's _jar.

Comment: You exported it to a directory named `biblioteca_jar`. It's not a JAR file.

Comment: Oh! I see. So IDEA didn't actually create a .jar then? It's confusing because the file HAS a .jar extension when looking at it through the file explorer. Anyway's, I'm not going to bother too much with the .jar for now. Thanks for the help!