# How to properly build java library?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I followed this instruction to build jar [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e).
I added it to another project by adding library in Idea 14 CE.
When I'm trying to create instance of some class from library I didn't got any autocomplete as I expected. What is the problem? All classes in my library are public.

Comment: I don't think that your library is the problem. Maybe you want to check the configuration of your IDE.

Comment: Do you want to build a jar or add dependency?

Comment: Is your lib is referenced in the classpath correctly? Or forget to add your lib in some "lib"/"libs" directory?