# How to create a JAR file with all classes and byte code in intelliJ or eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar, bytecode

I am new to java and currently doing a java project. This is the instruction on how to submit the project. Could anyone tell me how to do this in either intelliJ or eclipse?

Please submit a Java Archive (jar file containing all java classes you have written). Your jar file should
contain:
a) Contain source code for all classes
b) Contain executable (byte code) for all classes

Comment: Did you get the answer to the question? If so, please consider accepting it, otherwise add more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901370/104891) [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463915/104891).

Since you also need to include the sources, you will have to change the [resource patterns](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-compiler-settings.html) so that `.java` files are also copied to the compiler output and are therefore included in the `.jar` file.

By default `.java` files are excluded from copying, so you need to remove `!?*.java;` pattern that excludes them:

[image: exclude]

`!?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.aj`

becomes

`!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.aj`

Don't forget to change it back for your real world applications.

If you need a sample project for IntelliJ IDEA, you can download it [from my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891). It shows a more complicated example where additional dependent jars are included into the project using different ways (single jar and multiple jars).

Comment: Why would this be downvoted by anybody?  I voted it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you you are using eclipse you can follow one of the below ways as per your requirements.

**To Export the project you are working as jar:**

1) Right Click on the project you are working > Select **Export** from context menu.

[image]

2) Select Java > JAR File

[image]

3) Select the project to export as JAR. Enter the name for the generating jar file and then click on finish.

[image]

**If you are using Maven do following configurations to the pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <outputDirectory>C:\tmp</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>    
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>C:\tmp</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>    
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```