# IntelliJ: .java and .class files in .jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I want to export a java project to send it to a friend (AS JAR FILE).
He should be able to open the jar file via writing .zip right after the .jar file extension and should see the .java and the .class files.
I managed to export a jar-File as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

BUT: if I try to get the .java files by writing .zip right after the .jar file extension, there are .class files in the jar-archive only.

My question: how to automatically create the jar file in intelliJ with .class AND .java files in it?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping them separate.  A better way to expose source code to your friend is to put it in a github.

Comment: Did you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334536/104891? Does it work for you?

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but it does. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export source and compiled project into one file. But you can just export the project to *.jar and then go to `<drive>:/Users/<user>/IdeaProjects/<project>/src` and add all those files into archive and also add that exported jar file into that archive.