# Geckodriver on client side

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

I am doing a simple bot for automate users tasks in java/swing with selenium. Selenium needs geckodriver on client computer. How should I deliver that driver?

1. Put in the java package, commit to svn repo and then build jar which users run?
2. Outsource that task to our IT department, they will have to copy driver in path which we determine?

I want to know what is better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can response You what works for me. I created jar file of application, using IntelliJ [How to create a .jar file or export jar on IntelliJ (like eclipse java archive export)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e)
In maven project, I added path to GeckoDriver to main folder and I added driver file to main folder, too.

Remember, that applcation could stop works, when Firefox browser on Client conputer will be updated. So You can add Portable Firefox browser with stopped updating, and configure it in path to Browser.
Otherwise, You will have to release new vesions of your application with new driver (for new browser version).

Comment: So, you have geckodriver in jar file?

Comment: I don't want to change driver every time when browser will be updated. How often you need to do this?

Comment: The geckodriver and jar file are in the same, main folder (not in jar file). My client was locked updates for Firefox browser (it's easy on linux), so I didn't need to updated it.