# How to modifiy a java class in a library used in android studio,kotlin android development

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Basically im using the google maps sdk utility library and they have an IconGenerator class,and all i want to do is just add a new style,which is a color.

[image]

This is the class,and i just want to add a public static final int like all those styles and put the case in the switch statement to return a gray hex color code.How can i get acces to this class to modify it and use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

In my point, just download the source code from github and modify it yourseft then export that as an .jar

How to create an .jar from a java project by Intellij: [How to create a .jar file or export JAR in IntelliJ IDEA (like Eclipse Java archive export)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-in-intellij-idea-like-eclipse-java-arch)

Comment: So I download the code and I modify it in android studio then what?how do I use it

Comment: That really easy: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project>